# What is the best current way to get YouTube captions from API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I can see that a few people have asked on this subject in the past, but YouTube, especially in the past two years, has been doing a lot of work on their APIs, and it seems that a new question was warranted. I'm looking for a way to return time associated YouTube captions (auto-generated or otherwise) from an API call in JavaScript. I'm looking at the current YouTube documentation, and I can't quite figure it out.

I'm attempting to implement this API inside of a chrome extension, so I originally thought the best way to do this was to make a GET request to a link such as this one

https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=5MgBikgcWnY

where the video ID (which is found in the URL) is replaced in the v= section. I then noticed that these types of captions are not available for a lot of videos, so I'm searching for another way. Because I'm making a chrome extension, I'm hoping to find a method that is deployable. I'm not sure if this is true, but is it bad practice to keep your own API key in the code?

Here's what I have so far:

I first call the captions.list API, and get a JSON object with all the different captions, I select the English one and grab its captionID:

```
var urlOne = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&videoId=M7FIvfx5J10&key=[MY-KEY]";

fetch(urlOne).then(response => response.text()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Then, while not pictured here, I would take the English captionID and put it into the URL after the "captions/", and perform that get request.

```
var urlTwo = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/8yMV7mc691aTqjNxZ9zPHOdwpkL_e11j?tfmt=ttml&key=[MY-KEY]";

fetch(urlTwo).then(response => response.text()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Although when I try this, the response is "Login Required." I'm sure there's a security measure that I'm forgetting in this method, but my question is generally asking if this is the most optimized method to retrieve YouTube captions, and if it is, how I can go about solving security issues in a way that protects myself as well if I choose to put this extension up online.